# Passing arguments in a BST insert function by extracting data using sscanf

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, fgets, scanf

I am writing a program that reads students (id, name, surname, grade) from a text file (line by line) and then stores them to a Binary Search Tree by using id as a key. To read each line i use `fgets()` and to extract the words from the line is use `sscanf()`.

```
struct TreeNode* root = NULL;
FILE *text;
char *id, *onoma, *epitheto, *word, *line;
onoma = (char *)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
epitheto = (char *)malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
id = (char *)malloc(9 * sizeof(char));
float vathmos;

text = fopen("students.txt", "r");
if (text == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot read from the file!");
    exit(1);
}
```

**This is the loop where the data are extracted for each student:**

```
while (fgets(line, 50, text) != NULL) {
    printf("%d \n", root);
    sscanf(line, "%s %s %s %f", id, onoma, epitheto, &vathmos);
    printf("%s  %s  %s  %.3f \n", id, onoma, epitheto, vathmos);
    root = Insert(root, id);
}
```

And this is the insert function for the node:

```
TreeNode *Insert(struct TreeNode* root, char *data) {
    if (root == NULL) { // empty tree
        root = CreateNewNode(data);
    }
    // if data to be inserted is lesser, insert in left subtree.
    else if ((strcmp(data, root->id)) <= 0) {
        root->left = Insert(root->left,data);
    }
    // else, insert in right subtree.
    else if ((strcmp(data, root->id)) > 0) {
        root->right = Insert(root->right,data);
    }
    return root;
}
```

When I insert nodes "by hand" e.g.:

```
root = Insert(root, "AY881159");
root = Insert(root, "AA564510");
root = Insert(root, "AB784123");
```

the program works and the nodes are created and the tree can be manipulated.

But when the tree is created in the `fgets()` loop by getting the data from the `sscanf()`, there is a problem. While the variables store the data correctly (that's why I have the `printf()` after the `sscanf()` to check this), the `root` seems to reset and only the last student is kept in the tree.

Any ideas?

The code for the nodes is:

```
typedef struct TreeNode {
    char *id;
    struct TreeNode *left;
    struct TreeNode *right;
} TreeNode;
```

and

```
TreeNode *CreateNewNode(char *data) {
    struct TreeNode *NewNode = (TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    NewNode->id = data;
    NewNode->left = NewNode->right = NULL;
    return NewNode;
}
```

Comment: That is partial code so I have to ask: did you allocate memory for `char *line`?

Comment: suggest checking the returned value (not the parameter value) from `sscanf()` to assure the operation was successful.  It this case, any returned value other than 4 indicates an error occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted cannot be compiled, it makes it more difficult to answer questions.

You create all nodes in the loop from the same `id` buffer.  You need to make a copy of the buffer, either when calling `Insert` of preferably in the `CreateNewnode()` function.  You did not post the code for that, nor did you post the definition of type `TreeNode`. Here is a possibility:

```
TreeNode *CreatNewNode(const char *data) {
    TreeNode *node = calloc(1, sizeof(*node));
    if (node != NULL) {
        node->id = strdup(data);
        node->left = node->right = NULL;
    }
    return node;
}
```

There is no need to allocate the arrays for the parse phase, local `char` arrays are fine for this, but data you store to the tree should be duplicated so you can reuse the buffers from the parsing code.  Make the argument to `Insert` a `const char *data` to indicate the buffer will not be modified, nor owned by the tree after the call.

You must pass extra information to `scanf` to prevent buffer overflow.

Here is a modified version of the calling code:

```
int main(void) {
    struct TreeNode *root = NULL;
    FILE *text;
    char id[9], onoma[20], epitheto[30], line[256];
    float vathmos;

    text = fopen("students.txt", "r");
    if (text == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot read from the file!");
        exit(1);
    }

    // This is the loop where the data are extracted for each student:
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, text) != NULL) {
        printf("%d \n", root);
        if (sscanf(line, "%8s %19s %29s %f", id, onoma, epitheto, &vathmos) == 4) {
            printf("%s  %s  %s  %.3f \n", id, onoma, epitheto, vathmos);
            root = Insert(root, id);
        } else {
            printf("invalid line: %s", line);
        }
        // I'm curious how you are going to store the other data...
    }
    ...
}
```

The `Insert` function can be simplified:

```
TreeNode *Insert(struct TreeNode *root, const char *data) {
    if (root == NULL) { // empty tree
        root = CreateNewNode(data);
    } else {
        if (strcmp(data, root->id) <= 0) {
            // if data to be inserted is lesser or equal, insert in left subtree.
            root->left = Insert(root->left, data);
        } else {
            // else insert in the right subtree
            root->right = Insert(root->right, data);
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

A better API for `InsertNode` would be to take a pointer to the `root` pointer and return a pointer to the new node:

```
TreeNode *Insert(struct TreeNode **nodep, const char *data) {
     while (*nodep != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(data, (*nodep)->id) <= 0) {
            nodep = &(*nodep)->left;
        } else {
            nodep = &(*nodep)->right;
        }
    }
    return *nodep = CreateNewNode(data);
}
```

Comment: Yes, OP's "by hand" example works because the three strings inserted are in different locations.

Comment: i edited the question and added the code for the nodes.

Comment: @GeorgeBou: my guess was correct: you store `data` directly into `node->id`.  The contents of `data` gets modified by the next call to `sscanf`... in the end, the tree is corrupted and all nodes have the same `id`.

Comment: thank you for your answers. is it possible to explain to me a bit more why this happened? what does "the same buffer" mean? why does the id correctly changes in sscanf but the insert function gets corrupted?

Comment: @GeorgeBou: Your function `CreatNewNode()` stores its `data` argument in the `id` member of the new node.  The `data` passed to `Insert` is the `id` array allocated in `main`. So all nodes share the same `id` array, and this array gets overwritten for each call to `sscanf`.  The tree does not really get *corrupted*, but the nodes may no longer be correctly ordered since their `id` member changes.